# Chrome extension blocking Google Analytics external script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**Context:** I'm attempting to load Google analytics (univerisal) to a Chrome extension writtin in React.

**Problem:** Im runnning into the following errors

```
516.js:1 Refused to load the script 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
516.js:1 Refused to load the script 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I am using this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga) to install GA to my React project.

I did some digging and I'm supposedly meant to relax this restriction within my `manifest.json`. So I added the following line to `manifest.json`:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'"
```

Still this does not resolve the issue. Trying to figure a way to fix this but any help is welcomed! Thanks

Comment: ManifestV3 doesn't allow external scripts. There's probably no solution for GAPI yet.

Comment: ahh thanks. Came across this article - https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#remotely-hosted-code

I wonder, is the GA4 Javascript readily available for me to download and host in my project?

Comment: Found it - https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js